# Trying to unbind a click but when I do, my ajax load doesn't function correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem:**

I am doing a modal click function. On a click of a modal button I want to load the modal with an external page which works fine for the first time I click. When I click another link it doesn't work. The modal's data doesn't load.

With unbind click not on:

- https://gyazo.com/9f00a5856f656f45179eaca54d842224 (the first few work)
- https://gyazo.com/b50c47330ae031480ee99b9b135d3289 (the rest don't load)
- https://gyazo.com/441ab76b573569bf45873529c0d9838b (but my dropdown works)

Now, if I turn off the click of the button, the modal's work fine but the drop downs no longer work

- https://gyazo.com/073356ce57049f89722e7715f7ac957e (modals work)
- https://gyazo.com/58ccc01589f2dbf8e72c44774f025a09 (modals work)
- https://gyazo.com/261c9d7c1215a255b04b9bb7de6389cd (dropdown doesn't work)

I am in a pick, if I add the code some features work, some down and vice-versa. Here is my code that is breaking my dropdown but fixing my modals:

```
function setModalHandler() {

    // unbind all previously-attached events
    $("a[data-target='#globalModal']").unbind();

    // $(document).off('click');
    $(document).on('click', "a[data-target='#globalModal']", function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        $("#globalModal").modal("show");
        var target = $(this).attr("href");

        $.ajax({
            url: target,
            type: 'GET',


        }).done(function(data)
            {
                $(".modal-content").html($(data).find('.inner_modal'));

                $(".modal-header").prepend('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>');
            }) ;

    });
}
```

I aplogise for the multiple gifs, I couldn't make one long one. Any way, what I am trying to do is remove the click only for the modal, and not break my dropdowns

My modal buttons are like so:

```
<a href="http://google.com" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#globalModal" class="btn btn-default btn-xs tt"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
```

Fiddle (says modal not a function for some reason) https://jsfiddle.net/v8xnbppw/3/

Update: I have create a page with just the code I want in the modal and my code above is working, but when I have a full webpage inside the modal and use the find div and create the modal with that content is somehow breaks my script... this is the cause. How can I stop this from happning? It's this code:

```
$(document).on('click', "a[data-target='#globalModal']", function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    $("#globalModal").modal("show");
    var target = $(this).attr("href");

    $.ajax({
        url: target,
        type: 'GET',


    }).done(function(data)
        {
            $(".modal-content").html($(data).find('.inner_modal'));

            $(".modal-header").prepend('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>');
        }) ;

});
```

Comment: ` $("a[data-target='#globalModal']").unbind();` does not unbind `$(document).on('click', "a[data-target='#globalModal']",...`

Comment: Forked fiddle with working modal https://jsfiddle.net/94efyn41/

Comment: please show the html code.

Comment: Base on your edit, have you tried $('.modal-content').load(target + ' ' + '.inner_modal')? look at: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason removing the event and reattaching it. Try this:

```
// call this function once
function setModalHandler() {
  $(".modal-header").prepend('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>');
  $(document).on('click', "a[data-target='#globalModal']", function (ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();

      $("#globalModal").modal("show");
      var target = $(this).attr("href");

      $.ajax({
        url: target,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $(".modal-content").empty().append($(data).find('.inner_modal'));
        }
    });

  });
}
```

by the way, it will always load the same data because target is not changing anywhere in the code you provided

Comment: Still producing the same results :(

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a complete answer, but a general tip when I ran into similar problems. You have to make sure your event listener is in same function as when the DOM element is created. If you are looking for a "hacky" solution b/c of a deadline then add your listeners in the done method of the ajax call that creates the modal elements. That might mean you have multiple listeners that are exactly the same in your code (not very DRY) - but it will work until you have time to re-engineer your code.

Answer (score 1):

well this could happen for two reasons , events handling or something wrong with your html so
when handling click events some times it goes crazy because of event propagation so try adding this `ev.stopPropagation();` 
also double check that you're listening to events firing on the right a tag by checking if the href exists as link(contains http://) for example /http://.*/i.test(target)

```
function setModalHandler() {

// unbind all previously-attached events
$("a[data-target='#globalModal']").unbind();

// $(document).off('click');
$(document).on('click', "a[data-target='#globalModal']", function (ev) {
// stopping event propagation 
    ev.stopPropagation();
    ev.preventDefault();

    $("#globalModal").modal("show");
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    // verifying the a tag target
    if(/http:\/\/.*/i.test(target)){
      $.ajax({
        url: target,
        type: 'GET',
       }).done(function(data)
        {
            $(".modal-content").html($(data).find('.inner_modal'));

            $(".modal-header").prepend('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>');
        }) ;
        }

   });
}
```